# Need help understanding where to find Typescript types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I’m new to Typescript and recently started using it with React. I understand the basics of TS, but I’m confused on how to find/derive complex types.

In react for instance, an input element event gets the React.ChangeEvent. But I only know this because of stackoverflow. Otherwise I’d have no idea where to begin.

**How can I derive/find/ these types myself?** is there a place in the docs I’m missing? Is there some typescript hack? Would appreciate some guidance on how to improve in this way!

Thanks

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: @AfridiKayal vscode

Comment: Well most of the types should appear in autocomplete in vscode. For complex types like ChangeEvent<> and stuff, I usually temporarily write the callback associated with the type and hover over the parameters to copy the exact type. For example, I would temporarily write onChange={(evt) => {}) and then hover on evt to get the type. I keep forgetting the types as well so it is normal to look up this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find them here: `node_modules/@types/react/global.d.ts`
(there is also a folder for `react-dom` type definitions).